# How do I manage a login view in a navigation-based app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am designing an iphone application in objective C.
As of now, I have a UINavigationController in the beginning of my application 
and rest of the navigation was being handled from it.

Now I want to insert a login screen when the application is loaded.

How do I make it independent of my rest of the application ? 
i.e. As of now, I created a LoginViewController and added it to the NavigationViewController
of my app. When the user successfully logs in, the application continues with the next screen being pushed into the Navigation Controller.
But the problem with this approach is that, I can still go back to the initial login screen from the navigation item.

I have tried to hide the navigation bar from the first screen after login, but it removes the navigation bar from each of the subsequent screens.

The only working solution I can think of is that, I should manually hide the navigation bar in the start screen and make it visible in the subsequent screens.
Is there any other sane approach ?

Comment: You can present LoginScreen from the viewDidLoad of your first controller and after login you dismiss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do your nav controller disregarding the login screen, and then present the login screen using presentModalViewController:animated:

Answer (score 0):

present your LoginViewController in `viewDidLoad` for the the navigationController once the user login you dismiss it and continue your screen's flow as you want. also you can store that user login your app in the NSUserDefault so you can check this value and present the loginView in case he didn't login otherwise you show the navigation screen as normal

Answer (score 0):

If the user have not login in the app show LoginViewController and don't allow the user to go to navigation controller till then. Once login don't show LoginViewController directly show navigation controller so that user dont have to sign again and again.. To store user login information use NSUserDefaults. Retrieve the info at loading of the app and display controllers accordingly.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to store in UserDefaults some value - auto login / did login and when app is start you check this value if user isn`t in system u need to create login view controller and present it modaly.
Before your first view appear u need something like this -

```
BOOL didLogin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isLogin"];
if (!didLogin) {
    LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:loginVC animated:NO];
}
```

and when user is login you need to save value in user defaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isLogin"];
```

if you vant auto login feature you must store password in keychain

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to hide back button at your firstviewcontroller and unhide in rest all viewcontrollers.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
}
```

Otherwise another solution is that present the loginviewcontroller in the viewDidLoad method of your firstviewcontroller and as login completes dismiss the presented logincontroller on login button.

Even its the standard method to implement, all apps having login facility would have this type of flow.

Hope this will help you out.